# MySQL: Grouping Duplicate ID with IF Condition

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, rdbms

I have a table tblRater (which conatins all the users who can rate a topic) whose sample data is as follows:

```
RaterID | Name  |
=================
rater_1 |Katty  |
rater_2 |Batty  |
rater_3 |Ratty  |
rater_4 |Shatty |
rater_5 |Patty  |
```

there is another table tblAuthorizedRater (which contains the data about which rater is assigned to rate which topic) whose sample data is as follows:

```
TopicID | RaterID |
===================
topic_1 | rater_1 |
topic_1 | rater_2 |
topic_1 | rater_3 |
topic_2 | rater_2 |
topic_2 | rater_3 |
topic_3 | rater_1 |
topic_3 | rater_2 |
topic_6 | rater_1 |
```

So when I look up for the list of raters who are allowed to rate topic_1, I expect the following data:

```
RaterID | Authorized|
=====================
rater_1 | 1         |
rater_2 | 1         |
rater_3 | 1         |
rater_4 | 0         |
rater_5 | 0         |
```

The above table is basically list of all the raters from tblRater and the list of authorized raters for topic_1 from tblAuthorizedRater.

I tried doing the left join with tblRater on left and tblAuthorizedRater on right and an if condition. However the results I am getting repeats the RaterID and if I do a group by on it, I am not getting the expected result.

Just for reference, this is the query I am trying so far:

```
select
    tr.RaterID,
    IF(tar.TopicID = 'topic_1', 1, 0) as Authorized 
from tblRater as tr 
left join tblAuthorizedRater as tar
on tr.RaterID = tar.RaterID;
```

I also tried looking up at subselect, union, but none of it helped.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry What's he missing? He provided sample input, desired output, and the query he tried.

Comment: @Barmar I invite you to see the above too

Comment: @Strawberry I guess I touched all the points of the MCVE mentioned from the shared URL, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The accepted answer is highly upvoted. Consequently, I'm satisfied that it's self-explanatory.

Comment: @Strawberry Other than providing tabular data instead of DDL statements, he did everything suggested in the linked post. sqlfiddle's "Text to DDL" had no problem doing the translation.

Comment: @Barmar I agree that this example is trivial, but three issues tend to arise when DDLs aren't provided. 1. I can't be bothered, so I just move on to the next question - mostly this is fine because plenty of others can be bothered. 2. In a relational database, a PRIMARY KEY is a fundamental component of the table design. Without it, it's easy to misunderstand how data is related. 3. Often, problems simply boil down to a poor choice of data types or indexes. So it's nice to see those too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `topicID = 'topic_1'` in the `ON` clause, so you only select those rows from `tblAuthorizedRater`. Then check whether the join found a matching row by testing for `NULL`.

```
SELECT 
    tr.RaterID,
    tar.topicID IS NOT NULL AS Authorized
FROM tblRater AS tr
LEFT JOIN tblAuthorizedRater AS tar
ON tr.RaterID = tar.RaterID AND tar.TopicID = 'topic_1'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45a04ec/1)

Comment: F-king Genius! Thanks, Barmar! Couldn't have come up with that at least in this lifetime. Appreciated.